# Azure Functions Runtime - New install HTTP 401

Tags: azure-functions-runtime

After a Fresh install of Azure Functions Runtime, it appears that there is a process which is requesting an API key that fails with HTTP 401.

The specific call is GET

Response returned is: 
`{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}`

[HTTP 401 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73Q0.png)

Anyone else seeing this or is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue, when attempting to use just the server name to browser the site. Switching to using the Fully qualified name instead, while the error continued to show in the browser console, the site does actually load.

`https://servername` > 401 when accessing /api/token?plaintext=true
`https://servername.domain.local` > loads fine.